# ぼうやったら Dragonball Vol1. 84

Tags: conditionals

This is what the old country lady says when Goku "パンパン" her to check if she's a woman. Just before meeting Oolong for the first time.
What I can understand would be something like:
"Best if you do it with a stick".

But that looks like an inappropriate statement for a kid's manga!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to show us the full context, but this feels like 「坊やったら」 where 坊や and ったら are separate elements to me. That would be something like 'Oh, you [naughty] boy!' ったら after a word referring to somebody usually indicates some sort of exasperation with them. 坊や is a word for a young boy.

Note that 坊や doesn't necessarily always mean a *naughty* boy; the scolding element here is in ったら.